# What's the quickest way to add a feed to Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

From a feedburner feed by clicking on the Google icon, it's 3 clicks.

From Google Chrome with Google RSS browser extension I've managed 2 clicks (must click subscribe when in Google Reader).

Anyone know how to do 1-click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Better GReader extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6424/) offers an "Auto Add to Reader" option that skips the interim screen from Google that asks if you want to add to Reader or iGoogle. You still need to click to confirm, though.

The "Subscribe" bookmarklet on the [Official Google Reader blog](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2005/11/subscribing-to-feeds-via-little-google.html) does essentially the same thing.

(I don't think you're going to get around that confirmation in Reader. Even the "Add Subscription" tool in Reader itself requires two clicks to paste and accept.)

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect. The fastest way is to install [gleebox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/miinkdcjglbkbanpkghnkgkgbamdkgji), then type

```
g!rss
```

and you are added.

Perhaps less clicks other methods, but context is retained. Retaining context is the goal, no?